# Auto Import Job Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

We have an Dynamics CRM 365 installation on premise and I need to import accounts automatically when they were created in another system. 
Is there a way without SQL-insert in the AccountBase table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct SQL insert/update in any Dynamics 365 entity (ex. Accountbase) is unsupported.

You have to develop some push/pull integration between your external system & CRM using SDK service calls.

Jobs at regular intervals using Scribe or SSIS with Kingswaysoft connectors will be a good choice. Otherwise simple C# console application configured in Task scheduler can do pull/push the delta accounts.

Comment: Is the web api the best choice?